# Using QML and PyOtherSide Python module to create Windows desktop applications?

Tags: python, windows, qt, qml

I really like QML because I find it easy to understand and work with, but I don't know C++ and I don't really have the time to learn in. I consider myself a hobbyist programmer. I'm most familiar with Python and JavaScript.

I'd like to start making some Windows applications, and I though QML and the `PyOtherSide` module might work well.

The app would just query data from a SQL Server database, and display it to the user. So, the user might enter a code into a text box, hit a search button, which would query SQL Server, and display the results. They will also be able to create, update, and delete data from SQL Server - so a CRUD application.

I was thinking about using `pyodbc` to query SQL Server.

Is this just a bad idea? I know the best way would be to learn C# with .NET framework and maybe Windows Forms, but it seems a bit daunting.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why would C# be the best way? That is nonsense.

Comment: Okay.... can you expand a bit?

Comment: You could also look into using Python as the main language with QML/QtQuick as the UI, e.g. with PyQt or PySide